# how to pass value from parent to response using lotus script

Tags: lotusscript

how to pass value from parent to response using lotusscript or formula?

Comment: You need to provide more info. Does the response already exist, and you're trying to recalculate a field on the response when a field on the parent changes? Or are you trying to create a response with a computed field when a parent document is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write code, necessarily. So long as you have the "Inherit field values" form attribute checked, if you highlight or open the "parent" document, and then elect to create a response to it, that response will inherit the parent's field values, in specified fields. For example, if your parent doc has a `Subject` field, and you create a computed-when-composed field in your response form called, say, `OriginalSubject`, with the formula `Subject`, your response field will inherit its value from the parent doc on creation.

This is of course a user interface function. If you're creating response documents in the back-end, then you need to explicitly write field values from the parent to the response.